# Enable recycler view item to drag-drop over whole list while recycler view is child of nested scroll view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, android-nestedscrollview, nestedrecyclerview

I am facing issue while enabling full scroll in drag/drop gesture of recycler view item. Here, I have a bit complicated layout, I have attached one image for easy understanding. 
Where,

1. **A = RV 1 having drag, drop and swipe gestures, Horizontal layoutManager**
2. **B = RV 2 having swipe gesture, Horizontal layoutManager**
3. **C = RV 3 having swipe gesture, Horizontal layoutManager**
4. **D = RV 4 having grid layoutManager**
5. **E = Frame Layout / container having 2 RV** - only one will be visible at a time based on some logic
6. **F = Nested Scroll View**

Here, When I am selecting an item from `RV1 (A)`, It should scroll through all items of `RV1 (A)` But currently, It is getting scroll only into visible space of RV1. How can I make it work as expected?

Encountered Problem: It is happening because of `NestedScrollView`. It eats up a scroll event when `RV1 (A) item is dragged`. If I remove NestedScrollView, It can provide expected output. However, I can not remove it for sure!

Please Note: I can not change the layout and make it all fit into a single recycler view.

[image]

Comment: Check this out -- https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf

Comment: Thanks, @AnujSharma for the link! It's informative. However, I don't get my solution from there as they have documented gesture integration into one RecyclerView which I have already done. I'm facing issues in scroll when the drag gesture is enabled.

Comment: Hey @Dhara, not 100% sure about your requirements but somewhere I believe I think you can achieve this in a single RV. Is there any specific reason to keep multiple RV's?

Comment: @AnujSharma Yes, at the end it only worked when all data were fitted into one RV. However, I was just searching for a quick fix because of time shortage.

Comment: Yeah, recycler view could be a complex solution if not used properly. Anyway, glad you got working solution.